# Visual Studio - Accessing Warnings/Errors from Error List in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-list

I am a bit new to CSharp for a couple months, and I am trying to make "grab" the warnings/errors from the error list pane in Visual Studio and use them in my code, so that hopefully there can be a time where I can call this program after building something. Is there a class/property I can use to let me Access the Error List Window and its info?

Edit: by "grab" I mean just get the information in text(i.e. description or line number), so I can display it/write it to a file/etc.

Comment: What do you mean by grab? A screenshot or a text file or......

Comment: @ScruffyDuck I edited my question. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: OK then I think the answer is given below 8-)

Comment: What are the odds that you are actually writing a Visual Studio add-on?

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the MSDN documentation for [**`ToolWindows.ErrorList`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.toolwindows.errorlist.aspx).